# How to identify first column in Column Group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, grouping, ssrs-expression

Is there an expression or anyway of identifying the first column in a column grouping? I'd like the first column in the row to have a certain value and the rest another.

Like this:

```
If column in group = first, then firstValue, else otherValue
```

I've been looking and looking and cannot find an answer to this.

Comment: Did the following solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255270.aspx) function in SSRS to get the first column value.

```
=IIF(FIRST(Fields!Column.Value, "ColGrp") = "First", "FirstValue",  "otherValue")
```

Or you can also try something like this where you don't have to explicitily define the value of first column.

```
=IIF(FIRST(Fields!Column.Value, "ColGrp") = Fields!Column.Value , "FirstValue",  "otherValue")
```